# Somehow Apps Script can't get last day of the Month

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I want to get last day of Month for last Month to 5 Month ago, corresponds to ED1 to ED5.

If I set certain month at setOriginalDate(), I want it to get past last day of the month automatically.
To get last day of the Month, you have to set 0 day for next Month.

But some "ED" doesn't work correctly. when I set Month "11" for the setOriginalDate(), "ED2"(2 months ago) pushes out "10", not "9".
Could anybody tell me why this happens?

```
function setOriginalDate(){
  var SD = new Date();
  SD.setFullYear(2014);
  SD.setMonth(11);
  SD.setDate(1);
  SD.setHours(0);
  SD.setMinutes(0);
  SD.setSeconds(0);
  return SD;
  }

function electiveEndDate(OriginalDate){

  var ED = setOriginalDate();
  ED.setMonth(ED.getMonth()+1);//開始日の翌月の0日目を指定(その月の最終日)
  ED.setDate(0);  
  ED.setHours(23);
  ED.setMinutes(59);
  ED.setSeconds(59);

  switch(OriginalDate){
    case 'ED':
    return Utilities.formatDate(ED, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    break;

    case 'ED1':
    var ED1 = ED;
    ED1.setMonth(ED.getMonth()); //1ヶ月前 現在の0日目を指定(前月の最終日)
    ED1.setDate(0);  
    return Utilities.formatDate(ED1,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    break;
    case 'ED2':
    var ED2 = ED;
    ED2.setMonth(ED.getMonth()-1); //2ヶ月前
    ED2.setDate(0);  
    return Utilities.formatDate(ED2,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    break;
    case 'ED3':
    var ED3 = ED;
    ED3.setMonth(ED.getMonth()-2);　//3ヶ月前
    ED3.setDate(0);  
    return Utilities.formatDate(ED3,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    case 'ED4':
    var ED4 = ED;
    ED4.setMonth(ED.getMonth()-3);　//4ヶ月前
    ED4.setDate(0);  
    return Utilities.formatDate(ED4,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    case 'ED5':
    var ED5 = ED;
    ED5.setMonth(ED.getMonth()-4);　//5ヶ月前
    ED5.setDate(0);  
    return Utilities.formatDate(ED5,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }

}
```

Comment: The script is wrong, that is the problem. You can not add a month and expect it to work with months with 28,29,30,31 days.

Comment: Why not set the first day of each following month and subtract 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why using "setMonth()" and "setDate()" is giving you those results, however you can easily achieve this by instantiating a new Date object in each case and passing appropriate values to the constructor.

```
function electiveEndDate(OriginalDate){
  var timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var ED = setOriginalDate();
  ED.setMonth(ED.getMonth()+1);//開始日の翌月の0日目を指定(その月の最終日)
  ED.setDate(0);  
  ED.setHours(23);
  ED.setMinutes(59);
  ED.setSeconds(59);

  switch(OriginalDate){
    case 'ED':
      return Utilities.formatDate(ED, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      break;

    case 'ED1':
      var ED1 = new Date(ED.getFullYear(),ED.getMonth(),0);
      return Utilities.formatDate(ED1,timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      break;
    case 'ED2':
      var ED2 = new Date(ED.getFullYear(),ED.getMonth()-1,0);
      return Utilities.formatDate(ED2,timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      break;
    case 'ED3':
      var ED3 = new Date(ED.getFullYear(),ED.getMonth()-2,0);
      return Utilities.formatDate(ED3,timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    case 'ED4':
      var ED4 = new Date(ED.getFullYear(),ED.getMonth()-3,0);
      return Utilities.formatDate(ED4,timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    case 'ED5':
      var ED5 = new Date(ED.getFullYear(),ED.getMonth()-4,0);
      return Utilities.formatDate(ED5,timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I really couldn't understand why setMonth() doesn't work.